# Pass parameters to gvim while launching from a pop-up menu

Tags: windows, vim, parameters, startup

I am using gvim on Windows. Is it possible to pass my favorite options to gvim while launching it from the "Edit with Vim" entry of the right-clicked pop-up menu?

BR,Ruochen

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions at [Adding Vim to MS-Windows File Explorer Menu](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Adding_Vim_to_MS-Windows_File_Explorer_Menu), you can add / change the Windows registry to pass arbitrary commands to `gvim.exe` on startup. Vim takes both `--cmd {command}` (necessary when setting configuration variables to be considered in your `~/.vimrc`) and `-c {command}` (only evaluated *after* plugins have been loaded).

You can either directly change the settings (e.g. `gvim.exe -c "set list" "%1"`), or just set a flag (`let g:isPopupLaunch = 1`) and check that in your `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution may be easier, which is [adding Vim to the Send To menu](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Add_Vim_to_Windows_Send_To_menu). For that you just create a shortcut which passes the desired options, and place it in your shell:sendto folder.